# Error H14 in Heroku when deploying with Git

Tags: git, heroku

A little background: I am deploying a web application built with Python and Flask. I have a PostgreSQL database. This is my first project that I'm deploying on Heroku - I appreciate your patience. I am using a Mac. I have Procfile, requirements.txt, runtime.txt and gunicorn ready. The web app works perfectly fine it's just the last stage (deploying) that I am stuck at.

The issue is that when I do `git push heroku master`I receive `Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally`. `This is usually caused by another repository pushing to the same ref.` and I get H14 error when I do `heroku logs -t`.

My build log states:

Python app detected
! Requested runtime (python-3.7.6 gunicorn) is not available for this stack (heroku-18). ! Aborting. More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support ! Push rejected, failed to compile Python app. ! Push failed

What I've tried so far:

- Checking heroku for explanations. I tried `heroku buildpacks:clear` and the then `heroku buildpacks:add --index heroku/python` but then I get an error `Error: Expected an integer but received: heroku/python.`
- `git push --force heroku master`I get `[remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)`

Comment: can you try doing `git pull` locally since this error `Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally` suggests that remote and local branches aren't synchronized. Then try the Heroku commands after that and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. A silly question but - what do I put for <remote> and <branch>?

Comment: any branch name. For example, `git pull master` if its master that you are working on

Comment: That didn't work. I get fatal: Could not read from remote repository. (I typed git pull master heroku)

Comment: just `git pull master` and then do `git push heroku master`

Comment: That didn't work. I officially give up.

Comment: Final attempt try, `git fetch master` and `git push heroku master`

Comment: I just wanted to say that I have a Flask app working on Heroku, and the only way I was able to deploy it is to connect to a GitHub repository and deploy via the web interface. Good luck to you.

Comment: As far as I know GitHub only works with static web apps? Mine involves 2 html pages and a database... I was able to fix it by, as a newbie programmer, starting it over ¯\_(ツ)_/¯